# How to ignore unknown enum values?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm wondering what would be the best way to ignore/discard the unknown enum values in GraphQL/Apollo server.

Let's say my GraphQL schema defines array of enums "enum Service { Supermarket, TicketSales }" and it works fine now, but later on other service I'm using is adding some new values (e.g. Playground) and my client just doesn't support it and I would just like to ignore it and return the supported values without error.

What would be the best way to do this in GraphQL. My first idea was to make directive that would read the supported values from schema and ignore everything else, but after googling around I didn't find any good examples how to do it. Can you point me a direction where to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around I found something that I can use to get around my original problem, so I will post it here in case somebody else is wondering the same thing.

So my original problem was in short that I'm receiving several different "available services" kind of string arrays from another services and I was thinking to map them to enum for better typescript support etc. But the problem was that if I get some unknown value from another service, my graphql will fail.

So my original idea was to fix it with directive which I after all got working:

```
# In schema
directive @mapUnknownTo(value: String) on ENUM

enum SomeAttribute @mapUnknownTo(value: "__UNKNOWN__") {
  SomeAttribute1
  AnotherAttribute
  SomethingElse
  __UNKNOWN__
}
```

And the directive implementation is:

```
import { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } from 'graphql-tools';
import { GraphQLEnumType } from 'graphql';

export class MapUnknownToDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitEnum(type: GraphQLEnumType) {
    const { value = '__UNKNOWN__' } = this.args;
    const valueMap = type.getValues().reduce((map, v) => map.set(v.value, v.name), new Map<string, string>());
    type.serialize = (v: string): string => valueMap.get(v) || value;
  }
}
```

So this will map all the values not defined in schema into some custom value, which is not exactly what I originally wanted, but at least it's not giving an error, so it's okay-ish.

I'm still not 100% sure if directives are way to go on cases like this, but at least it's one possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your resolver function will accept arbitrary strings, then you can use a custom scalar type, or just `String`.

```graphql
"""
The type of a service.  `Supermarket` means..., and
`TicketSales` means...; any other value is ignored.
"""
scalar Service
```

GraphQL generally places responsibility on the client to conform to the server's expectations, rather than making the server try to support any request.  There are a couple of places you can reasonably expect an enum value like this to appear:

```graphql
enum Service { Supermarket, TicketSales }
type Query {
  inAReturnValue: Service!
  asAQueryParam(service: Service!): Node
}
type Mutation {
  asAMutationInput(service: Service!): Node
}
```

In particular it may not make sense to tell the server "make the type of this object be a playground" if the server just doesn't understand that.  Conversely, if the server knows about "playground", it could return it in cases the client may not expect.  Having an enum here makes it explicit what the server knows about.  The server has said what it supports and it's the client's responsibility to cooperate.

Note that it's possible for the client to find out if the server supports playgrounds, if it's an enum value, and this might help it inform its behavior.

```graphql
query GetServiceTypes {
  __type(name: "Service") {
    enumValues { name }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, there's some good ideas I need to think about. In my case we have plenty of different "supported services" kind of types which practically are array of strings and the reason I would like to map them to enums is that it would make clear for the client which values can be expected instead of just random strings, and of course I would get typescript typings for them too. Over the time we will probably have some new services introduced that we don't support yet and of course my server needs to somehow filter those out until we build support for them.

Comment: and the data I'm dealing with is coming from another services, so basically I may just suddenly start getting some new values I didn't know about. Since my graphql schema already defines the allowed values, I'm wondering is there some easy way to allow just those and ignore everything else? Maybe with custom resolver & info parameter somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Update to the above response with newer version of `graphql-tools` (2023)

```js
export const unknownEnumDirective = (directiveName: string) => {
  return {
    unknownEnumDirectiveTypeDef: gql`directive @${directiveName}(value: String) on ENUM`,
    unknownEnumDirectiveTransformer: (schema: GraphQLSchema): GraphQLSchema => {
      return mapSchema(schema, {
        [MapperKind.ENUM_TYPE](enumTypeConfig) {
          const enumDirective = getDirective(schema, enumTypeConfig, directiveName)?.[0];
          if (enumDirective) {
            const valueMap = enumTypeConfig
              .getValues()
              .reduce((map, v) => map.set(v.value, v.name), new Map<string, string>());

            enumTypeConfig.serialize = function mySerialize(outputValue: unknown): Maybe<string> {
              if (typeof outputValue === 'string') {
                return valueMap.get(outputValue) ?? 'UNKNOWN';
              }
              return 'UNKNOWN';
            };
            return enumTypeConfig;
          }
          return enumTypeConfig;
        },
      });
    },
  };
};
```

As of writing this this unfortunately does not work as the provided serialization function gets overwritten with the default serializer due to an issue in `graphql-tools`. But there is a PR to fix this in the repo.
https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/pull/5120

If you want to use this functionality you could use https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package to apply the PR change in your repo.